# Sitecore Publishing Service Deadlock

Tags: sitecore-client, publishing-service

I have Sitecore Publishing Service 1.1 installed on my Sitecore 8.2 initial release instance. Sometimes, publishing job gets executed successfully, and sometimes it gets interrupted. Kindly see below error:

```
2017-04-03 11:59:24.140 +03:00 [Error] Error during publish of 0c3cbc45-3bc2-41a9-b3d3-badcb0f5458d - Error: "Transaction (Process ID 80) was deadlocked on lock | generic waitable object resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."
2017-04-03 11:59:29.130 +03:00 [Error] Error persisting completed job status. ID:0c3cbc45-3bc2-41a9-b3d3-badcb0f5458d, Status:Failed, Message:"Transaction (Process ID 80) was deadlocked on lock | generic waitable object resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.". Error - "Transaction (Process ID 80) was deadlocked on lock | generic waitable object resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."
2017-04-03 11:59:29.131 +03:00 [Error] Error processing scheduled task : "PublishTask-7891ad2cafbf40dd868192fb48e1955d"
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction (Process ID 80) was deadlocked on lock | generic waitable object resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader(Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<ExecuteImplAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Service.Sql.PublishJobQueue.PublishJobQueueProvider.<StopJob>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\TC\BuildAgent\work\c9f151fb6c9b4087\src\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Service.Sql\PublishJobQueue\PublishJobQueueProvider.cs:line 231
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.PublishJobQueue.PublishJobQueueRepository.<StopJob>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\TC\BuildAgent\work\c9f151fb6c9b4087\src\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing\PublishJobQueue\PublishJobQueueRepository.cs:line 103
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Tasks.PublishTask.<OnExecute>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\TC\BuildAgent\work\c9f151fb6c9b4087\src\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing\Tasks\PublishTask.cs:line 169
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Scheduling.ScheduledTask.<Run>d__29.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:33593899-f60b-4fd4-b672-23a464000537
Error Number:1205,State:51,Class:13
```

Any idea what the problem would be?

Comment: could you please let us know what is this "0c3cbc45-3bc2-41a9-b3d3-badcb0f5458d" item ? Are you encountering error only with this item ? can you try with "__NeverPublish" for this item ?

Comment: This is the Job ID of the publishing process

Comment: What do you mean by: try "__NeverPublish"? could you please elaborate?

Comment: Please upgrade to Publishing Service v2.0, and if you continue to encounter the problem, please provide more information such as how often it occurs, what type of publish is being performed when the error occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Deadlocks occur if your EventQueue is too large. Make sure you clean the EventQueue often and keep as little data as possible, preferably below 1000 items. Check [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/10/23/sitecore-eventqueue-deadlocks-how-to-solve-them-and-how-to-avoid-them/amp/)

Comment: Can you please provide more information? Random blog post from 2014 might not apply to the Sitecore 8.2

Comment: Yeah the above link does not apply to my case. It is not giving that type pf deadlock since that I don't have any issues with the event queue and the configuration. Thanks though..